# Elasticsearch Query with And and Or Condition

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I have data like below in Elastic

```
{
  "_index": "prod",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "aa",
  "_source": {
    "input_type": "log",
    "sourcetype": "sourcetypeapp1",
    "message": "APP COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626ec|001 ErrorMessage: Some error"
    "type": "log",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
  }
}
```

I wanted to search all the message which contain below data in message :-

```
(Message : "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eA|001" AND Message:"ErrorMessage")
Or
(Message : "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eB|002" AND Message:"ErrorMessage")
Or
(Message : "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eC|003" AND Message:"ErrorMessage")
```

i dont know much about elasticsearch query,

i have tried below simple query its not working (with only one condition):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "Message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eA|001"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
( (condition11 AND condition12) OR (condition21 AND condition22) )
```

If this is what you want to achieve, try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eA|001" } },
              { "match": { "message": "ErrorMessage"}}
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eB|002" } },
              { "match": { "message": "ErrorMessage"}}
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": { "message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eC|003" } },
              { "match": { "message": "ErrorMessage"}}
            ]
          }
        }        
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But in your example, condition12 and condition22 are same. In that case, you can rewrite it as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "message": "ErrorMessage"}},
        { 
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              { "match": { "message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eA|001" } },
              { "match": { "message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eB|002" } },
              { "match": { "message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eC|003" } }
            ]
          } 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this query i am not getting correct result as if any message contain 4a1d all are getting displayed.But i want this entire phrase to match in whole text, "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eA|001"

Comment: I thought you wanted to know how to use multi OR condition of AND conditions. If you want to match whole text, you should be using wildcard not match. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query Match analyzes the text you provide and then construct the query.

Comment: But it depends on how you defined the schema. If message property/field is not defined as index: not_analyzed (refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping-index.html), you won't be able to use wildcard to solve this. Because your text would have been tokenized and saved as multiple strings rather than one full string. In that case, you can not match against complete text as it is not there. You have to write multiple match queries of each part (eg: COMPANY, 80d596f6, 2082 and etc.)   inside a single must as you want it to retrieve lines that contains all of them.

Comment: i didn;t understand can you please provide example

Comment: its seems to me hyphen is causing issue, acting as wildcard. i am not sure how to avoid that

Comment: did you try using wildcard instead of match ? update your question with elastic search mapping at least for the property: message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with something like

```
{
 "query": {
  "match": {
     "Message": "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eA|001"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: how can i add multiple and or condition ?

Comment: you can use should (OR) and must (AND) inside bool query

Comment: I have tried this query i am not getting correct result as if any message contain -2082- then all are getting displayed.But i want this entire phrase to match in whole text, "COMPANY|80d596f6-2082-4a1d-bcfc-740478f626eA|001. Look like due to hyphen